# Why won't my sunrise/sunset applescript give me the correct output?

Tags: applescript, date-sunrise

I'm trying to write a code to determine sunrise and sunset for the current date and location. I use [LocateMe](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/locateme/) for the latter, and I call it with `do shell script "~...LocateMe"`, then use the `-f` function to get the latitude, longitude, and altitude. As the altitude is in meters, I multiply it by 3.28084 to get feet.

The remainder of the code simply uses the [sunrise equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation#Calculate_sunrise_and_sunset) to calculate sunrise for that time and location. I have [Satimage.osax](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/15492) to handle the trig functions, but as it calculates in radians while the above equation for some reason uses degrees, I'm careful to multiply the degrees by π/180 and the inverse trig formulae by 180/π.

The code outputs a Julian date, as it should. But it outputs sunrise for today, for instance, as July 18.914151470176876 2017 - just before midnight tonight. A few minutes off for a miscalculation in coordinates is one thing, but it can't be *that* far off. So where did I go wrong?

```
set n to ((current date) - (date "Saturday, January 1, 2000 at 12:00:00 PM")) / days
set n to n div 1

set longitude to do shell script "~/Library/Application\\ Support/LocateMe/LocateMe -f \"{LON}\""
set latitude to do shell script "~/Library/Application\\ Support/LocateMe/LocateMe -f \"{LAT}\""
set altitude to do shell script "~/Library/Application\\ Support/LocateMe/LocateMe -f \"{ALT}\""
set altitude to altitude * 3.28084

set Jstar to (n - (longitude / 360))

set M to ((357.5291 + (0.98560028 * Jstar)) mod 360)

set x to 1.9148 * (sin (M * pi / 180))
set y to 0.02 * (sin (2 * M * pi / 180))
set z to 3.0E-4 * (sin (3 * M * pi / 180))
set C to (x + y + z)

set lambda to ((M + C + 180 * 102.9372) mod 360)

set q to 2.4515455E+6
set r to (0.0053 * (sin (M*pi/180)))
set s to (-0.0069 * (sin (2 * lambda*pi/180)))
set Jtransit to (q + Jstar + r + s)

set d to ((asin (sin (lambda * pi / 180) * (sin (23.44 * pi / 180)))) * 180 / pi)

set numerator to (sin ((-0.83 - (1.15 * (sqrt (altitude))) / 60) * pi / 180) - (sin (latitude * pi / 180) * (sin (d * pi / 180))))
set denominator to (cos (latitude * pi / 180) * (cos (d * pi / 180)))
set HRA to ((acos (numerator / denominator)) * 180 / pi)

set sunrise to (Jtransit - (HRA / 360))
set sunset to (Jtransit + (HRA / 360))
```

After noting a location in which I wasn't so careful in my π/180's, the formula now consistently logs sunrise and sunset at roughly 19 hours later than it should be. So, for instance, sunrise this morning was [6:30 AM or so](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21680/what-exactly-is-the-sunrise-equation-outputting/21694#comment37127_21680). The formula outputs tonight at 1:45 AM instead. I have [confirmed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149514/discussion-between-donielf-and-scott-hunter) that all of the calculations are correct; the problem is that it outputs the wrong Julian day.

**EDIT:** I realized that `n` in the equation is today's day. My formula originally included the leftover fraction of the day. I added line 2 to account for that; it's perhaps a little weird, but that was the best I could think of.

That said, the formula now gives 7:30 PM for sunrise - still way off, but closer than before.

Comment: Where in the intermediate calculations do things go awry?

Comment: @ScottHunter That's exactly what I can't figure out. I seem to have my code the same as the sunrise equation, but I can't figure out where it differs.

Comment: Look at the actual *values*; if the result is off, some intermediate step must be also, which narrows down where the problem is.

Comment: @Scott Found one problem in the calculations for Jtransit. Plugging in the exact same formula to desmos gives 2.44957965041E+6 whereas AppleScript is giving me 2.457953788952E+6. Looking more closely at my calculations for r and s made me realize I wasn't as careful as I thought in multiplying all my angles by π/180... :)

Comment: Bugs I can't seem to squash, though: They can't agree on the declination angle `d` past the thousandths. As for `numerator`: they can't agree on the first sine expression. While my applescript has both the second and third sines negative and desmos has both of them positive, multiplying them together yields the same result, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Remember that variables have a limited amount of precision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149514/discussion-between-donielf-and-scott-hunter).